# Converting Double For Loop to Numpy Linear Algebra for Dual Form SVM

Tags: python, numpy, svm, linear-algebra

I'm trying to create a Dual Form SVM and it's running very slow but correctly right now. I currently have this for the objective function (which is the bottleneck)...

```
ij = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        ij += y[i]*y[j]*a[i]*a[j]*np.dot(x[i].T, x[j])
ij /= 2
```

This runs very slow. I somehow need to convert this to linear algebra to speed it up using NumPy but I tend to struggle with that.

FYI: a, y, and x are all the same length. a and y contain all floats. x is a two dimensional vector of floats.

Comment: Small sample arrays would make testing our answers easier.  Otherwise we'd have to make up a test case or two.

Comment: The best way to do this depends on size of the arrays. The simplest thing (which is also very good on larger arrays is to use einsum. eg. `np.einsum("i,j,i,j,ix,jx->",y,y,a,a,x,x,optimize="optimal")/2`

Comment: @max9111 wow, great improvement! I thought on using `np.einsum` but couldn't get it work as expected and finally did it the old way. Do you know what `optimize="optimal"` does internally?

Comment: Finding the optimal contraction (minimizing the number of FLOPs). I recommend to have a a look at `np.print(np.einsum_path("i,j,i,j,ix,jx->",y,y,a,a,x,x,optimize="optimal")[1])` to get a feeling what is actually done by einsum. The source code can be found here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/einsumfunc.py Anyway, always provide some relevant Input data, it is much easier to give an answer if someone know how large the input arrays are. A simple np.random.rand() is enough.

Comment: @max9111 Thanks for you reply! You should post it as an answer, it's better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a better/cleaner way, but here it goes my best.

```
def np_way():
    # Compute 1st part: y[i]*y[j]*a[i]*a[j]
    ay = a*y
    ya = np.outer(ay, ay)
    # print(ya)
    # Compute 2nd part: np.dot(x[i].T, x[j])
    _dot = np.outer(x, x)
    dot = _dot[::2, ::2] + _dot[1::2, 1::2]
    # print(dot)
    return (ya * dot).sum()/2
```

You can uncomment to debug it.

I've put your code in a `original_way()` function and compared ir with `np_way()` so I could `timeit`:

```
%timeit original_way()
%timeit np_way()
1 loop, best of 3: 708 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.21 ms per loop
```

The results were with a length of `500`, being `np_way()` around 220 times faster than `original_way()`.

Comment: @TrevorDalton Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
y[i]*y[j]*a[i]*a[j]*np.dot(x[i].T, x[j])
```

I think the ij sum can be written as a broadcasted outer product, followed by a flattened sum

```
temp = y[:,None]*y*a[:,None]*a*(x.T@x)

temp = temp.sum()
```

I've written this without testing so there may be bugs.

or

```
 ya = y*a
 temp = np.outer(ya,ya)
 temp *= x.T@x
```